# Find all instances of a type associated with another type

Tags: grails

I have some classes that look like this:

```
class User {
    boolean enabled
    String username
}

class ExampleClass {
    User firstUser
    User secondUser
}
```

My end goal is to find all instances of `User` where `enabled == true` OR the instance of `User` is associated with `ExampleClass`.

Where this code is running I don't have access to the variable names `firstUser` or `secondUser`.

**With that said, I need to be able to find all instance of `User` associated with `ExampleClass`, disregarding which variable (`firstUser` or `secondUser`) the association was made through.**  How do I do this?

**UPDATE:**

The best I can come up with is this method in my `User` domain class.  I the example I gave above I have an `ExampleClass` which has multiple fields of the `User` type.  In fact I have multiple classes with multiple fields of the `User` type.  This is why I get the domain class from the object being passed in instead of just typing `ExampleClass`.

```
static List findAllEnabledOrAssociatedWith( Object obj = null ) {
    if( obj?.id ) { // Make sure the object in question has been saved to database.
        List list = [] 
        obj.domainClass.getPersistentProperties().each {
            if( it.getReferencedPropertyType() == User ) {
                def propertyName = it.getName()
                list += User.executeQuery( "SELECT DISTINCT ${propertyName} FROM ${obj.class.getSimpleName()} obj INNER JOIN obj.${propertyName} ${propertyName} WHERE obj =:obj", [ obj: obj ] )
            }
        }
        list.unique()
        return User.executeQuery( "SELECT DISTINCT users FROM User users WHERE users.enabled=true OR users IN(:list)", [ list: list ] )
    } else {
        return User.executeQuery( "SELECT DISTINCT users FROM User users WHERE users.enabled=true" )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sql = '''
    from 
        User u, 
        ExampleClass ex 
    where 
        u.enabled = 1 or (u = ex.firstUser or u = ex.secondUser)'''
def users = User.findAll(sql)
```

Comment: "Where this code is running I don't have access to the variable names `firstUser` or `secondUser`." <-- quote